# How to create a layer/movieclip with scrollbar in flash?

Tags: flash, flash-cs5, flash-cs4, flashdevelop

I am creating a game in flash. It needs a scroll bar. So I want to know how to create a layer with scrollbar? . I know how to link a textfield with scroll bar. Similarly is it possible to link a movieclip/layer with scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ScrollPane` component. (press ctrl+f7 to see components window)
then set a movieclip as its source:

```
your_scrollPane.source=your_movieclip;
//customize other properties such as ScrollPolicy & ...
```

**edit:**
if you don't want use actionscript:
1-set `AS Linkage` for your movieclip (in library panel)
[image] 
2- set source property for your ScrollPane
[image]

Comment: Thanks dude... Actually I tried using SrollPan component...but when i input the source value in property window, i get an error saying "Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: file:"